# call pl/sql procedure in oracle from Hibernate with a return parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function ,
this function return two parameters : req_type and req_seq.

this is the code of PL/SQL.

```
declare
    req_type number;
    req_seq  number;

    TEST_PKG.insert_req(001,req_type,req_seq );
    dbms_output.put_line('req_type='||req_type);
    dbms_output.put_line('req_seq='||req_seq);
end;
```

I need to call this function from Hibernate.

I didn't find the exact way to do this work from hibernate

I tried yo use this code :

```
public EmpEntity insertReq(String numEmp) {
    String query = " call TEST_PKG.insert_req(" + numEmp + ",req_type,req_seq ) " ;

    SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
    sqlQuery.executeUpdate();

    sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(
            EmpEntity.class));

    List<EmpEntity> list = sqlQuery.list();

    EmpEntity empEntity=list.get(0);
    empEntity.setRequestType(.....);
    empEntity.setRequestSec(....);

    return empEntity;
}
```

Comment: You Pl/Sql is invalid. There's a `BEGIN` missing

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below. Here we are setting in and out parameters before execution.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
        .createStoredProcedureQuery("proc_name")
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, 
            ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Long.class, 
            ParameterMode.OUT);

    query.execute();

    Long res = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
```

You can replace
You can find docs for StoredProcedureQuery here
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html

Comment: thank you for your response,
the problem is that I used hibernate3.jar
so I cannot use StoredProcedureQuery.

I hope there is a solution using hibernate3